# TransactionReceipt has empty children array for PrivateKey.fromStringECDSA() but not for PrivateKey.generateECDSA()

Tags: javascript, ecdsa, hedera-hashgraph

When I run the code example for [transfer-using-evm-address.js](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-sdk-js/blob/develop/examples/transfer-using-evm-address.js), unmodified, it works.

However, when I change this line:

```js
    const privateKey = PrivateKey.generateECDSA();
```

to this:

```js
    const privateKey = PrivateKey.fromStringECDSA(process.env.TARGET_HEX_PRIVATE_KEY);
```

the script throws an unexpected error. There is literally no difference apart from the private key being randomly generated, versus the private key being set from an input string.

Why is this occurring? How to rectify?

For the record, the transfer does indeed succeed,
and the balance of the account increases,
and I can see this in the wallet (MetaMask),
as well as in the block explorer [0.0.3996359](https://hashscan.io/testnet/account/0.0.3996359?app=false&pt=1&p2=1&ph=1&p1=1&k1=1680795222.058549460).

However, trying to perform a transfer HBAR transaction from within MetaMask fails with this account, so it seems like the remainder of the steps are indeed needed.

---

Details:

Output #1 - for `PrivateKey.generateECDSA()`

```
% node ./transfer-using-evm-address.js
Private key: 3030020100300706052b8104000a042204205972cfade03879583d2a30a8013b07a4b2a6d6497ef4454a1be9bfd70e6e29e7
Public key: 302d300706052b8104000a032200023cd10457c01d01db85467d587c7d31f29bd147f2213f9727d91fadb7fb2cc405
Corresponding evm address: 144daf7b20f09b468e18f29e72c1f166a2bf0447
TransactionReceipt {
  status: Status { _code: 22 },
  accountId: null,
  fileId: null,
  contractId: null,
  topicId: null,
  tokenId: null,
  scheduleId: null,
  exchangeRate: ExchangeRate {
    hbars: 30000,
    cents: 195739,
    expirationTime: 2023-04-06T16:00:00.000Z,
    exchangeRateInCents: 6.524633333333333
  },
  topicSequenceNumber: Long { low: 0, high: 0, unsigned: false },
  topicRunningHash: Uint8Array(0) [],
  totalSupply: Long { low: 0, high: 0, unsigned: false },
  scheduledTransactionId: null,
  serials: [],
  duplicates: [],
  children: [
    TransactionReceipt {
      status: [Status],
      accountId: [AccountId],
      fileId: null,
      contractId: null,
      topicId: null,
      tokenId: null,
      scheduleId: null,
      exchangeRate: null,
      topicSequenceNumber: [Long],
      topicRunningHash: Uint8Array(0) [],
      totalSupply: [Long],
      scheduledTransactionId: null,
      serials: [],
      duplicates: [],
      children: []
    }
  ]
}
Account ID of the newly created account: 0.0.3999408
Account 0.0.3999408 does not have public key, therefore it is a hollow account
HAPI transaction status: SUCCESS
The public key of the newly created and now complete account: 302d300706052b8104000a032200023cd10457c01d01db85467d587c7d31f29bd147f2213f9727d91fadb7fb2cc405
```

Output #2 - for `PrivateKey.fromStringECDSA(...)`

```
% node ./transfer-using-evm-address.js
Private key: 3030020100300706052b8104000a04220420fb11afc5d508036ac7a9df9f1eb7cea551e4a7b738c2c70da099fe5f379f3364
Public key: 302d300706052b8104000a032200027a753c29cc9f0ea0b6ccf0614676daeba3da0dbd5f54ef9850ad3878ded4e077
Corresponding evm address: 07ffaadfe3a598b91ee08c88e5924be3eff35796
TransactionReceipt {
  status: Status { _code: 22 },
  accountId: null,
  fileId: null,
  contractId: null,
  topicId: null,
  tokenId: null,
  scheduleId: null,
  exchangeRate: ExchangeRate {
    hbars: 30000,
    cents: 195739,
    expirationTime: 2023-04-06T16:00:00.000Z,
    exchangeRateInCents: 6.524633333333333
  },
  topicSequenceNumber: Long { low: 0, high: 0, unsigned: false },
  topicRunningHash: Uint8Array(0) [],
  totalSupply: Long { low: 0, high: 0, unsigned: false },
  scheduledTransactionId: null,
  serials: [],
  duplicates: [],
  children: []
}
file:///Users/user/code/hedera/hedera-scratch/transfer-using-evm-address.js:102
    const newAccountId = receipt.children[0].accountId.toString();
                                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'accountId')
    at main (file:///Users/user/code/hedera/hedera-scratch/transfer-using-evm-address.js:102:46)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v18.15.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the script using both `generateECDSA` and `fromStringECDSA`, but was unable to reproduce the problem. My guess is that the error is occurring because the receipt is not being propagated to the node that the SDK sent the request to. It's possible that the transaction was sent to Node A, but the SDK is attempting to query the receipt from Node B. As a result, the node may not be able to locate the transaction due to some delay, resulting in the error. Please let me know if you have a reliable way to reproduce the problem

Comment: thanks for the answer - I re-ran the script, and it consistently does *not* work on the same address (the one above), however was able to work with a new address. I assume that this was some sort of glitch on my first run?

Comment: separately, I need some help understanding what steps 6, 7, and 9 in that script actually do (hollow account, HAPI thing, and complete account)

Comment: A hollow account is the Hedera auto-created account. it's created from transferring HBAR to an EVM address. The account object is created but it's still incomplete. You can read more about hollow account here or create a separate question on StackOverflow ;) https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/core-concepts/accounts/auto-account-creation#auto-account-creation-evm-address-alias